# Looking to combine excel files without added space to the right 'between files'

Tags: python, pandas

With this code, I have successfully combined the excel files however the individual files are separated in such a way that it becomes an endless horizontal scrolling file. I have attached an image with sample data to show what I mean.

I need help getting it to instead add a new line at the end of one file and then starting on the first column again. Is this even possible? I know it might not make sense to have it like this but it is how I want it.

I appreciate any help I can get.

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

folder = '/Users/karldamus/Developer/Python/combineExcelFiles/files'


xlsx = []
dataframes = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            xlsx.append(file)

for file in xlsx:
    file = folder + "/" + file
    dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(file))

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

join.to_excel(folder + "/" + "output.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: Your issue is with your `concat`, not with your writing to excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually open the file and add it:

```
with open(folder + "/" + "output.xlsx") as f:
  s = f.read.strip()

with open(folder + "/" + "output.xlsx",'r') as k:
  k.write("\n")
  k.write(s)
  k.write("\n")
```